# Is father-daughter relation or relationship? Is a feeling of hate relation or relationship?

Tags: meaning

I am confused relation with relationship.

per this [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/15209/362807)

> both can mean “the way in which two or more concepts, objects, or people are connected”

Assume Yang is Alice's father, father-daughter is their relation or relationship?

Alice hates her father, is this feeling their relation or relationship?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the dictionary defintions:

**Relation**: the way in which two or more people or things are connected.

**Relationship**: the way in which two or more people or things are connected, *or the state of being connected*.

The "state" of the connection is something covered by "*relationship*" but not "*relation*". For example, someone may say that they do not have a relationship with their father - however, they are still *related*. People can be related whether they like it or not, by blood ties or family marriages; but *relationships* require effort and can be good or bad, strong or weak.

In your example of "Alice hates her father", this is a comment on their *relationship*. They will always be related.